# Callback after multiple AJAX calls with SQlite transactions

Tags: jquery, ajax, sqlite

I have got multiple AJAX calls with SQlite transactions to add data. For some reasons one of the AJAX calls not executing but hideLoadingScreen() fires fine.

I am using this code to count callbacks:

```
showLoadingScreen();

var callbackCount = 0;

function ajaxCallback() {
  ++callbackCount;
  if (callbackCount >= 3) {
  hideLoadingScreen();
  }
}
```

And three of my AJAX calls with SQlite transactions look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            $.each(data.result, function (i, item) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO db_table (id, type, title) VALUES (?,?,?)', [item.ID, "update", item.post_title]);
            });
            ajaxCallback();
        });
    }
});
```

Or is there any other way how to count callback after succesfull - db.transactions????

Answer (score 0):

Move `ajaxCallback();` inside `$.each(...)` loop because `success` callback executes once after AJAX call is over

**edit**: After `hideLoadingScreen();`, reset counter to zero like `callbackCount = 0;`

Comment: I tried but the problem is $.each(...) is being executed a few times in each AJAX call so my callback counter stops showing Loading Screen  before finished other AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

**Application must wait for the AJAX Calls to finish before starting a transaction and adding the data elements in cordova-sqlite-exe**

until ajax calls finished , all statements will be in queue state after completion of ajax calls then only all the statements start executions **one by one**

if you want to count the number of rows are inserted ,**Come out from the success** **callback** perform the Select query to return the length of table.